# A Messy Definite Integral $\int_0^1 (x\ln x)^n dx$ or a Trick?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^1 (x\ln x)^n dx$$

How should I proceed with the above integral? I'm actually supposed to solve it for n = 50, but I don't think reduction formulae would be a good idea (or would they?)

I couldn't establish a closed form for the above integral in terms of $n$. How do I do that? Could some please guide me in the right direction, or provide a solution for better understanding? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by reduction.  In fact, integrate by parts to get
$$
\int_0^1 x^m (\log x)^n\;dx = -\frac{n}{m+1}\int_0^1 x^m (\log x)^{n-1}\;dx
$$
Using this $n$ times, we get
$$
\int_0^1 x^m (\log x)^n\;dx = \frac{(-1)^n n!}{(m+1)^n}\int_0^1 x^m\;dx
=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(m+1)^{n+1}}
$$
The case $m=n$ is your integral.

**side note**
This also works when $m$ is not an integer...
$$
\int_0^1 x^{1/2} (\log x)^n\;dx = \frac{(-1)^n n!}{(3/2)^{n+1}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
Use substitution $\ln x=-u$ and then apply the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) definition. The result will simplify to $\dfrac{(-1)^nn!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$.